# Filling a list with Window objects using EnumWindows

Tags: c++, windows, list, pointers, winapi

I'm trying to fill a list with 'Window" objects of all active Windows but I can't figure out a way to save the Window information in my windowList. The windowList is passed to the callback function through the lParam parameter.

Here is my current code:

```
std::list <Window> windowList; //in center.h


//in center.cpp:

void Center :: detectWindows()
{
    EnumWindows(detectWindowsProc, (LPARAM)&windowList);
}

BOOL CALLBACK detectWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM inputList)
{
    if (IsWindow(hwnd) && IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) && IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
    {
        TCHAR TCharTitle[100];
        GetWindowText(hwnd, TCharTitle, 100);

        std::string title = convertTCharToStr(TCharTitle);

        Window * windowPtr;
        windowPtr = (Window*)inputList;

        Window newWindow((int)hwnd, title, true);
        *windowPtr = newWindow;

        std::cout << (int)hwnd << "  -  " << title << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I try to print out every element in windowList through a for loop, a error message pops up, saying "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: list iterators incompatible"

This is the for loop:

```
void Center::printWindowList()
{
    for (std::list<Window>::iterator it = windowList.begin(); it != windowList.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << ' ' << it->getTitle();
}
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback function you're treating the `inputList` parameter as a `Window*` instead of a `list<Window>*`. Try this:

```
BOOL CALLBACK detectWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM inputList)
{
    if (IsWindow(hwnd) && IsWindowEnabled(hwnd) && IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
    {
        TCHAR TCharTitle[100];
        GetWindowText(hwnd, TCharTitle, 100);

        std::string title = convertTCharToStr(TCharTitle);

        auto windowPtr = reinterpret_cast<std::list<Window>*>(inputList);
        windowPtr->push_back(Window((int)hwnd, title, true));

        std::cout << (int)hwnd << "  -  " << title << std::endl;
    }
    return true;
}
```